# Rejecting the Torah of the Arizal

Tags: halacha, mysticism-kabbalah

Is there anything halachically wrong with a 21st century Orthodox Jews rejecting as false the Kabbalistic doctrines that were promulgated by R Isaac Luria and R Moses Cordovero?

Since one of Rambam’s thirteen principles of faith is the acceptance of the divinity of the oral Torah, would this include kabbalah or chasidut?

Comment: *Is there anything wrong* - according to who?

Comment: Do you suspect a 21st century orthodox jew is different from any other jew at any other time? Why? Do you have any reason to believe this is different from any other claim, where one should always believe the truth, the whole truth, and nothing but the truth? What? Remember to [edit] your question to clarify. Also remember that one line questions are almost always really bad.

Comment: @DoubleAA. Sorry. My question was was only one line because that was my whole question. I wasn't going to make it longer just to sound more sophisticated. Nothing wrong with asking bad questions. Lo ha'baishan lomeid.

Comment: @MarkA. You should make it longer to make it better, not to make is sound more sophisticated. There is something wrong with asking poor question on Mi Yodeya; we don't handle any question ever. You don't seem to understand how this site works or what that Mishna means. You can learn more about the former in our [help], particularly at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DoubleAA and how do you interpret "*v'lo hakapdan melamed*"?

Comment: @Loewian You can ask new questions at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask IAE site policy is not based on any Mishna and is not designed to accommodate everyone.  If someone can't work in our structure then they should go elsewhere.

Comment: @DoubleAA. I would like you be more careful about following question guidelines. Please point out to me specifically what the problem with this question is, so that I can learn for future attempts. Please be specific and do not refer me to the how to ask link. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkA I did that already above and you didn't like it.

Answer (score 5):

In general, Orthodox Judaism grants the right to question just about anything. That being said, Judaism is still **in pursuit of truth**. We are **not** in pursuit of **the right to be contrary** just to prove we have that right.

**So, in order to reject something as false, you need to be able to understand it completely in the first place. Only then, may you voice a valid opinion on it.**

If you do not understand something, but your Torah true Rebbeim (bona fide) teachers do say something is false; you may exercise your "emunah" to trust their judgment (until such time as you are convinced otherwise).

Therefore, the Teachings of the Arizal and Ramak are not granted any special privilege or "diplomatic immunity". If you have a valid argument against their teachings in a Torah way, then you may hold that opinion.

However, most heavily accepted Rabbis of the Jewish people from the past, have a pretty good track record with the truth. Don't be surprised if you find it is very difficult to refute the Arizal or the Ramak. :)